# How can I limit string characters to utf8mb3

Tags: mysql, go, character-encoding

I created in Go some conversion for decoding inputs.
It is working as charm, (thanks to "golang.org/x/net/html/charset"), but now I have to limit output to characters contained only in utf8mb3.
As far as I know, go default "builtin" is full utf-8.
The problem is that the underlying database setting is locked by vendor rules and setted to utf8mb3 (yep mysql), we can't change those.

So far I'm using this to limit characters and rewrite "unallowed" to "*":

```golang
 //compile our regexp. if fails, return undecoded
        allowedCharsREGEX = `[^ěščřžýáíéúůťňĺľŕĚŠČŘŽÝÁÍÉÚŮŤŇĹĽŔ!?§©®±%¼½¾¿ß÷£¥¢~¡#&_\"\\/:;a-zA-Z_0-9\t\n\r\ ]`
        reg := regexp.MustCompile(allowedCharsREGEX)
        procString := outStr

        // replace not allowed chars
        procString = reg.ReplaceAllString(outStr,"*")
```

to limit output characters but want to expand it to utf8mb3 char list.
From documentation seems unicode IsValid is full utf8.
Any possible "quick solution"?

Go v.1.13, ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Off-topic but why are you using Go 1.13? It's unsupported, latest is Go 1.16.

Comment: You should never install Go via dpkg/apt. Use the [official channels](https://golang.org/dl/).

Comment: Ubuntu's Go package lags behind. It's not the "official" way to install Go. The official way is to get it from [golang.org/dl](https://golang.org/dl/). They support the 2 most recent major versions (currently Go 1.16 and 1.15).

Comment: Flimzy,icza i would gladly manual reinstall go every time new version goes out, if i have time. but normaly have more then 300 servers to maintain, so no time. thats why im using official repos versions.

Comment: @Viker You can write a script that downloads the latest and replaces the old version, it doesn't matter how many computers you have to run it on.

Comment: @Viker: It takes about 5 minutes every 6 months. And saves time, because then you don't get on StackOverflow to ask about unsupported versions, then spend more than 5 minutes discussing why you're using obsolete software. And the number of servers you use is obviously irrelevant, since you're not going to be installing the Go compiler on your servers. And you're also not going to be manually installing things on 300 servers.

Comment: But all that is tangential, since, to my knowledge, nothing related to your question changed since Go version 1.13.

Comment: i was refering to update my "workdesktop" go packages. that "desktop" is actualy pretty hard blocked inside DMZ and cant get out on internet, only to official repos. Yep i can avoid that, but so far everything worked, so didnt go out of repo versions.

Comment: Why not switch to full UTF-8, aka `utf8mb4` in MySQL?

Answer (score 3):

Not everything should be done with a regexp.

utf8mb3 contains all runes from the BMP which can be encoded with 3 Bytes in UTF-8.

```
sb := &strings.Builder{}
for _, r := range input {
    if r < 0xFFFF {
        sb.WriteRune(r)
    } else {
        sb.WriteByte('*')
    }
 }
 return sb.String
```

Comment: Working excelently. Thank You Volker

Comment: why `r < 0xFFFF` and not `r <= 0xFFFF`?

Comment: @cpr4t3s Why do you think it would matter?

Comment: just wondering if 0xFFFF is invalid in some way, hence being discarded

Comment: @cpr4t3s Its not invalid „in some way“.